# como puedo mostrar la lista de alumnos en este codigo?

Tags: php, html, sql

Este es el HTML que debería de mostrar la lista de alumnos dependiendo del curso seleccionado; sin embargo, simplemente aparece en blanco, parece ser un error en la consulta SQL. Tengo una javascript, que deberia permitir mostrar dichos alumnos y una funcion en php que obtiene los alumnos por su curso y especialidad.

Este codigo deberia mostrar la lista de alumnos por curso y unos checkboxes que registraran su asistencia.

Esta es la tabla sql

```
CREATE TABLE `curso` (
`IdCurso` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IdTurno` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IdEspecialidad` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Descripcion` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NroAula` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CantidadAlumnos` int(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdCurso`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Este es mi código

```
            <label for="fecha">Fecha:</label>
            <input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha" value="<?php echo $fecha ?>">
            <label for="curso">Curso:</label>
            <select id="curso" name="curso">
                <?php
                $cursoQuery = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM curso");
                while ($row = $cursoQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row['IdCurso'] . "'>" . $row['Descripcion'] . "</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <label for="materia">Materia:</label>
            <select id="materia" name="materia">
                <?php
                $materiaQuery = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM materia");
                while ($row = $materiaQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row['IdMateria'] . "'>" . $row['Descripcion'] . "</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <div class="form-container">
                <label for="especialidad">Especialidad:</label>
                <select id="especialidad" name="especialidad">
                    <?php
                    $EspecialidadQuery = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM especialidad");
                    while ($row = $EspecialidadQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['IdEspecialidad'] . "'>" . $row['Descripcion'] . "</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
                <label for="turno">Turno:</label>
                <select id="turno" name="turno">
                    <?php
                    $turnoQuery = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM turno");
                    while ($row = $turnoQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['IdTurno'] . "'>" . $row['Descripcion'] . "</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button id="btnMostrarAlumnos" type="button">Mostrar Alumnos</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

este es el codigo de obtencion del alumno

```
function obtenerAlumnosPorCursoYFecha($cursoNombre, $especialidadId, $fecha) {
    global $conn;
    $alumnos = array();
    
    if (!empty($cursoNombre)) {
        $alumnosQuery = $conn->prepare("SELECT a.CiAlumno, a.Ci, a.Apellido, a.Nombre, a.IdSexo, d.descripcion AS curso, e.descripcion AS especialidad
            FROM alumno AS a
            LEFT JOIN sexo AS s ON a.IdSexo = s.IdSexo
            LEFT JOIN curso AS d ON a.IdCurso = d.IdCurso
            LEFT JOIN especialidad AS e ON d.IdEspecialidad = e.IdEspecialidad
            WHERE d.descripcion = :cursoNombre AND e.IdEspecialidad = :especialidadId");
        $alumnosQuery->bindParam(':cursoNombre', $cursoNombre);
        $alumnosQuery->bindParam(':especialidadId', $especialidadId);
        $alumnosQuery->execute();
        $alumnos = $alumnosQuery->fetchAll();
    }

    return $alumnos;
}
```

Comment: Buenas, Gabriel, bienvenido al sitio. No aparece ahí arriba el código donde se carga un alumno dependiendo de lo que hayas seleccionado. ¿Puedes añadirlo? Por otro lado puede que la consulta select donde se recupera el alumno te esté fallando, intenta capturar el error y mostrarlo, así como añadirlo aquí

Comment: Buenas de nuevo, has añadido el código que te pedía como si fuera una respuesta. Por favor, EDITA la pregunta y añadelo ahí. Por otra parte, no veo en el código original nada llamado cursoNombre.